# Change scene after few seconds in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm a newbie. At this time, I want to change scene after a few seconds (about 3-5 seconds). But I don't know how to do. I know schedule but I don't want it loops. I mean it just works only once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, running a main menu scene after a 2.0s delay from the splash screen.

```
// In the init()
this->schedule(schedule_selector(CSplashLayer::RunMainMenu), 2.0f);

// function in the splash layer class
void CSplashLayer::RunMainMenu(float dt) {
  // tell CCDirector to run main menu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
CCScene *pScene = GameLayer::scene();
CCTransitionPageTurn *crosssfade = CCTransitionPageTurn::create(3,pScene, true);
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(crosssfade);
```

You can use any Transition effect to change the scene with any time to take this transition to complete

Comment: I just want to change scene without any transition effect. How to do it?

Comment: Then you have to use schedulerOnce which run only once whenever you want to run this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `this->scheduleOnce(<#SEL_SCHEDULE selector#>, <#float delay#>)`. This way you can acheive what you want.